# Xamarin computer vision

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am trying to create a Xamarin application using Azure computer vision API, I got the API key and endpoint URL whenever i click a picture and set in image view and then describe image function not working and i am not getting output captions, my code is below:

```
 private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {         
    await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

    try
    {
        if(!CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported&&!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("INFO", "CAMERA NOT AVAILABEL", "OK");
        }
        else
        {
             var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
             {
                 Directory="Images",
                 Name="test.jpg"
             });

             if (file==null)
             {       
                 await DisplayAlert("ERROR", "FILE NOT FOUND", "OK");
                 return;
             }

             img.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
             {
                 var stream = file.GetStream();
                 return stream;
             });

             var visionapi = new ComputerVisionClient(new ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials(""));
             visionapi.Endpoint = "";

             var desc = await  visionapi.DescribeImageInStreamAsync(file.GetStream());

             foreach (var tag in desc.Captions)
             {
                 cap.Text = cap.Text + "\n" + tag;
             }
         }
    }
    catch(Exception )
    {
        await DisplayAlert("", "ERROR", "OK");
    }
}
```

`DescribeImageInStreamAsync` functon is not working it is moving into catch block after few minutes with the below error:

> Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVisionErrororException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Not Found'
>   Exception

Comment: What exception are you getting?  "(catch Exception ex)" follow by "await DisplayAlert("ERROR", ex.ToString(), "OK");

Comment: Or, you know, debug it and see what exception turns up.

Comment: Iam getting Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVisionErrororException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Not Found'